# Running function on clicking a letter on the keyboard of Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, keyboard

I have a function that should run when pressing the keyboard letter of Android:

The application is built in HTML + PhoneGap

My input:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="Refresh();" onkeypress="Refresh();" id="MyInput" />
```

refrsh function:

```
function Refresh()
{
   alert('Now Refresh!');
}
```

alert appears only when delete a letter and when clicking on the space, why?

Comment: if possible, use onchange event instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I used oninput event, and it worked